# Is there any function/procedure as ReplaceString but for whole words on Delphi?

Tags: string, delphi

Is there any function/procedure as `ReplaceString` but for whole words on Delphi? I just need to replace substring to the new one when it's a whole word. For example:

```
substring - > newstring
substring, -> newstring
substring123 -> substring
```

Comment: You can read [Is There An Efficient Whole Word Search Function in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1678814/576719), and make your own SearchReplace function for whole words.

Comment: I take that back, appearently there is a bug in the SearchBuf() with the `[soWholeWord]` option. See [SearchBuf soWholeWord unexpected output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25877986/576719).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in regex library to do this. For example:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.RegularExpressions;

const
  InputString = 'a Substring, substring123, some more text';

begin
  Writeln(TRegEx.Replace(InputString, '\bsubstring\b', 'newstring', [roIgnoreCase]));
end.
```

Comment: Unfortunately it works extremely slow comparing with `StringReplace`.

Comment: You can probably improve perf by compiling the regex. Of course, there's nothing in the question that mentions perf .......   ;-)