# SearchBuf soWholeWord unexpected output

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

When testing [StrUtils.SearchBuf](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.SearchBuf) with `[soWholeWord,soDown]` option, some unexpected results occurred.

```
program Project1;

Uses
  SysUtils,StrUtils;

function WordFound(aString,searchString: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SearchBuf(PChar(aString),Length(aString), 0, 0, searchString, 
    [soWholeWord,soDown]) <> nil;
end;

Procedure Test(aString,searchString: String);
begin
  WriteLn('"',searchString,'" in "',aString,'"',#9,' : ',
    WordFound(aString,searchString));
end;

begin
  Test('Delphi','Delphi');   // True
  Test('Delphi ','Delphi');  // True
  Test(' Delphi','Delphi');  // False
  Test(' Delphi ','Delphi'); // False
  ReadLn;
end.
```

**Why are `' Delphi'` and `' Delphi '` not considered a whole word?**

What about a reverse search?

```
function WordFoundRev(aString,searchString: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SearchBuf(PChar(aString),Length(aString),Length(aString)-1,0,searchString, 
    [soWholeWord]) <> nil;
end;

Procedure TestRev(aString,searchString: String);
begin
  WriteLn('"',searchString,'" in "',aString,'"',#9,' : ',
    WordFoundRev(aString,searchString));
end;

begin
  TestRev('Delphi','Delphi');   // False
  TestRev('Delphi ','Delphi');  // True
  TestRev(' Delphi','Delphi');  // False
  TestRev(' Delphi ','Delphi'); // True
  ReadLn;
end.
```

I'm not making any sense of this at all. Except that the function is buggy.

Same results in XE7,XE6 and XE.

---

**Update**

[QC127635 StrUtils.SearchBuf fails with [soWholeWord] option](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=127635)

Comment: there are different bugs mentioned in the QC e.g. [Report #:  122357](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=122357)

Comment: @bummi, yes I searched the QC and found no match for this occurrance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me. Here's the code that does the search:

```
while SearchCount > 0 do
begin
  if (soWholeWord in Options) and (Result <> @Buf[SelStart]) then
    if not FindNextWordStart(Result) then Break;
  I := 0;
  while (CharMap[(Result[I])] = (SearchString[I+1])) do
  begin
    Inc(I);
    if I >= Length(SearchString) then
    begin
      if (not (soWholeWord in Options)) or
         (SearchCount = 0) or
         ((Byte(Result[I])) in WordDelimiters) then
        Exit;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  Inc(Result, Direction);
  Dec(SearchCount);
end;
```

Each time round the `while` loop we check if `soWholeWord` is in the options, and then advance to the start of the next word. But we only do that advancing if

```
Result <> @Buf[SelStart]
```

Now, `Result` is the current pointer into the buffer, the candidate for a match. And so this test checks whether or not we are at the start of the string being searched.

What this test means is that we cannot advance past the non-alphanumeric text to the start of the first word, if the searched string begins with non-alphanumeric text.

Now, you might decide to remove the test for

```
Result <> @Buf[SelStart]
```

But if you do that you'll find that you no longer match the word if it is located right at the start of the string. So you'll just fail in a different way. The right way to deal with this would be to make sure that `FindNextWordStart` doesn't advance if we are at the start of the string, and the text there is alphanumeric.

My guess is that the original author wrote the code like this:

```
if (soWholeWord in Options) then
  if not FindNextWordStart(Result) then Break;
```

Then they discovered that words at the start of the string would not match and changed the code to:

```
if (soWholeWord in Options) and (Result <> @Buf[SelStart]) then
  if not FindNextWordStart(Result) then Break;
```

And nobody tested what happened if the string started with non-alphanumeric text.

Something like this seems to get the job done:

```
if (soWholeWord in Options) then
  if (Result <> @Buf[SelStart]) or not Result^.IsLetterOrDigit then
    if not FindNextWordStart(Result) then Break;
```

Comment: `And nobody tested what happened if the string started with non-alphanumeric text`. Sigh, so many years and nobody found this before. The test is trivial and it makes me wonder whether the RTL is unit-tested by Emba at all. Thanks, I will file a QC later.

Comment: Hmm. Don't get me started!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I replaced the original code with your suggestion code and still doesn't work, the example in question returns the same results. Delphi 10.1 or 10.2.

Comment: This issue still seems be with Delphi 10.4

Answer (score 1):

Fix Version/s: 11 Alexandria Release 2 :)

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20731

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).