# How replace a string only if not contains in another string?

Tags: string, delphi, replace, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572202/9708179) to replace a string in a file. Works fine replacing all matching strings (also recognizes sensitive case). Now i'm need that it can replace a string **only if not contains in another string**, for example:

- UserName - *Change only here*
- [`GetUserName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea) - *Not change here*

How make (utilizing the same code)?

Comment: You want to "match whole words". (Because surely you want to replace "UserName" even if it is contained inside a larger string "The variable is named UserName today.".) In other words, you want to replace an instance of the search phrase iff it is a word in the string, and not strict substring of a word.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852384/is-there-any-function-procedure-as-replacestring-but-for-whole-words-on-delphi and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678572/is-there-an-efficient-whole-word-search-function-in-delphi/1678814#1678814 ?

Comment: Use a regex for this